# Bind a jquery function on an input field loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery ui datepicker. On test page it works fine.

```
<div><input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="" />                     </div>      

<script>
$('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

But if the input field is loaded via ajax, how should i put the script ? I tried this

```
$("#basic_example_1").live("click", function(){
  $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

not working. Appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `datetimepicker()`  after the `success` function of ajax and after the input is appended:

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  success:function(){ 
      //do your stuff..  append your input which is already done I guess
      $('#appendedInputID').datetimepicker(); //id of appended input 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#basic_example_1').click(function(){
    $('#basic_example_1').datepicker('show');
});
```

or if your input field is going to be dynamic, create a class 'date' and assign this class for every input field that require date picker and add this script:

```
    $('.date').click(function(){
        $('.date').datepicker();
        $(this).datepicker('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#basic_example_1', function(){
    ...etc...
});
```

This way it is bound to the document rather than #basic_example_1, so anything that arrives through ajax that fits the criteria will be picked up.

Comment: sorry silly qn, but in the ..etc... did you mean $(this).datetimepicker(); ? I am new to jquery

Comment: In this case, yes. Or whatever else you wanted in there. This just binds the event to the document, so everything will be caught and then dealt with if the elements and action fit the criteria.

Comment: that is essentially what was being done before. `live` is on the way out.

Comment: Just actually tried this for myself. If you are using jqueryui, you could try using the correct function `datepicker`. Also `focus` seems to work better. http://jsfiddle.net/FTAnD/

Comment: Thanks. I put the handler right after ajax finish and it seems to work.  Also, this is datetimepicker i am trying to get. An example i found online, it has got time as well.

Comment: That's cool, glad it works. The 'correct function' comment wasn't meant in the sarcastic way that it look to me now.

Comment: No worries, Din't even occur that way. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick example, its not getting the input via ajax but is `dynamically` creating it and thanks to `Qoop` reference to using `focus` it works better now, when I tried with `click` it had strange results. This should help you:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#basic_example_1', function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

For an example please visit: http://jsfiddle.net/a3zWv/

Answer (score 0):

After Ajax call, in success function, you can write as follows:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
      url: //url
      type: //post/get
      ...
      ...
      success: function(..){
                //Display/load text field
                jQuery("#basic_example_1").datetimepicker();
               },
      failure: function(..){
                   //code for failure
                 }



 });
```

I guess it works.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will go with this method. :)